# DjangoRestFramework - How to pass a serializer form to the frontend?

Tags: django, angularjs, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I'm using the DjangoRestFramework. I have a UserSerialzer in my serializers.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', )
```

This is my urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^users$', views.user_list.as_view()),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.user_detail.as_view()),
]
```

and this is my views.py file:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            # context['users'] = User.objects.all()
            return context

class user_list(APIView):
    """
    List all users, or create a new user.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class user_detail(APIView):
    """
    Get, update or delete a specific user.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.DATA)
        if serialzier.is_valid():
            serializier.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

When I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/users, DjangoRestFramework has the API page which shows a list of users (JSON objects) and it also has a form which has "username", "password" and "email". This form seems to be validating correctly (checks if the email is a real email, and checks if username is unique and less than 30 characters). Is there a way for me to pass this form to the frontend when a user goes to 127.0.0.1:8000 (calling HomePageView)?

I'm in the process of using AngularJS on the frontend (not sure if this information helps or not).

Comment: I don't think your question makes sense. Django's forms are primarily for validating data. That should occur on the server side. They can also be used to render an HTML form, but that isn't what the forms primary purpose is. Is it the rendered HTML you want to send to the front end?

Comment: @wobbily_col yes, I have the User object and a UserSerializer. When a POST request is sent to /users, the view does "if serializer.is_valid(): serializer.save()". I'm planning on changing this to "if serializer.is_valid(): User.objects.create_user()" but nonetheless, I want to be able to give a <form> to the frontend (which has username, email and password and validates it based on the User model's requirements) and if the users hits the submit button, it should send the data to /users and create the User object.

Comment: @wobbily_colI I noticed that the default DRF API frontend (the page I see when I visit /users) has a form which does this when I put "serializer_class = UserSerializer" in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here are a few things I think we might need to point out. Django forms are normally what you would use to create a new user, with a post request just like you are trying to do through DRF. Now you can do this through DRF, but thats not really what it is for, django forms would be more appropriate for what you are doing. Unless of course you are building an API that you want API users to be able to use to create new users on your platform, in which case continue onward. I am linking a tutorial I used when I first started using DRF with Angular, maybe you will find it helpful.

http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html

Comment: After looking around the whole internet for a viable tutorial on browsable api, you saved me!